# How to move my navbar back (I translate it on css)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building my navbar, i wrote the code and now i want to click on my burger and open the navbar. The thing is that I don't know how to do it, I've been trying in javascript but I can't find a solution.

```js
const navBar = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
  const nav = document.querySelector(".nav-links");

  burger.addEventListener("click", () => {
    nav.classList.add(".nav-open");
  });
};

navBar();
```

```css
.nav-open {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 24vh;
  background: #ffafaf;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  transform: translate(-100%);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="logo">
    <h1>iCosmetics</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="burger">
    <svg
      class="menu"
      width="30"
      height="16"
      viewBox="0 0 30 16"
      fill="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <line
        x1="15"
        y1="15"
        x2="30"
        y2="15"
        stroke="black"
        stroke-width="2"
      />
      <line x1="10" y1="8" x2="30" y2="8" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
      <line y1="1" x2="30" y2="1" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-open">
    <div class="contact">
      <h2>Contact</h2>
      <p>3108248125</p>
    </div>
    <div class="social">
      <h2>Social</h2>
      <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
      <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

It is hidden by CSS and is supposed to be shown by JavaScript.
The JavaScript code doesn't work.

This is how it looks closed:
[image]

This is how it's supposed to look when opened:
[image]

Comment: Your code looks quite good. You will need the CSS for the hidden nav bar and the visible navbar. You can toggle the states by adding or removing a CSS class like you already do. I would recommend to use `display: none` or `oppacity` properties to hide it instead of the off-screen translation. In your code there is no element with the class `nav-links`

Comment: Welcome!
Your line: `const nav = document.querySelector(".nav-links");` returns nothing because there is no `".nav-links"`, and it will give an error when you try to use `nav.classList`.

Comment: @lupz Annoying thing about `display:none` is that it isn't animatable. Best to just hide it off screen somewhere with a transform, like he's doing. Perhaps with a `pointer-events: none` when hidden. Definitely if you plan on using an `opacity` to hide something.